# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una aplicación en un servidor y simular que una persona lo usa?

Tags: servidor

Me gustaría saber cómo podría ejecutar una aplicación de escritorio típica de Windows o Linux en un servidor externo y simular que una persona la usa.

Un ejemplo de lo que estoy tratando de conseguir sería lo siguiente:

> 1. Obtener datos desde MySQL con un script de PHP.
> 2. Enviar los datos al programa que simularía el comportamiento humano y que está instalado en un VPN (el VPN podría ser el mismo del
>      script de PHP o uno externo).
> 3. Hacer que en el servidor externo se abra una aplicación que yo elija o programe con anterioridad y se simule que una persona hace
>      clic en los menús y botones de ella.
> 4. Con los datos recibidos, hacer una serie de operaciones en la aplicación como: editar contenido, escribir en campos de texto, mover
>      el ratón para hacer clic. Y después guardar el resultado.

¿Conocéis algún programa que pueda instalar en un servidor VPN y que me permita hacer esto?

Comment: No entiendo algo. ¿La aplicación que se va a probar es de escritorio o web? Porque mencionas que creas scripts en PHP (es raro ver PHP en escritorio pero existe). En caso que intentes probar una aplicación web, podrías simular el comportamiento humano mediante [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La aplicación que se usaría es de escritorio, ésta estaría instalada en un servidor externo. Y yo le enviaría a ese servidor información obtenida desde MySQL con algún script de PHP. Lo que principalmente necesito es algún programa que me permita simular el comportamiento de una persona en una aplicación de escritorio. Gracias!

Comment: Es extraño que intentes manipular una aplicación de escritorio desde una aplicación web como lo sería un script de PHP. Si estás amarrado a PHP, desconozco cómo resolver tu dilema. Sino, podrías utilizar algo como [TestWhite](https://github.com/TestStack/White), [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) o crear el tuyo desde 0 usando algo como [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) de Java.

Comment: Como tal no veo el modo de hacerlo, como han comentado, es muy extraño el problema a resolver. Lo único que conozca de simular acciones humanas es algo como Machine Learning. A lo mucho el intento sería de Web App a Web App y la receptora sería asp.net que ejecutara X programa o un .bat que ejecute el programa pasándole los datos y parámetros y que ese programa (si es desarrollado por uno) haga la respectiva operación de acuerdo al parámetro.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Necesito programas como esos 2 que me pasaste. Mi idea es (1) obtener unos datos desde una base de datos MySQL con un script de PHP, (2) pasar dichos datos a un script diseñado con uno de los programas que me pasaste (3) ese script se conectaría con unos credenciales a una app de escritorio y (4) realizaría una serie de operaciones con los datos que le envié. ¿Crees que es posible lograr todo esto? Gracias!

Comment: Lo único que te rompe la solución es PHP. Nuevamente, si piensas trabajar con algo de escritorio, ¿por qué PHP? PHP está orientado a **la web más que a escritorio**. Obtener información de una base de datos lo puedes hacer en otras plataformas. De que es posible, lo es. No sé si PHP sea una limitante, pero te sugeriría utilizar otro LP para esta labor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Esta solución se implementaría en una plataforma online que funciona con PHP al completo, de ahí viene la idea de usar PHP para obtener los datos de la BD. ¿Puedo explicarte con más detalle por Skype y luego publicamos aquí la solución final?

Comment: Has dado una mirada a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

Comment: La plataforma puede estar escrita en PHP o en otro lenguaje, eso no implica que la plataforma de pruebas esté escrita en el mismo LP.

Comment: Simplemente lo que quieres hacer es realmente muy complicado. Lo más importante es que definas en forma clara que es lo que TU has programado / programarás y lo que no.
(1). La plataforma PHP ya existe? (2) El programa de escritorio ya existe? (3) El MySQL ya existe?.
Por que insisto con esto? Porque en el hipotético caso de que el (1) ya exista y el (3) también pero no (2), tendrías más posibilidad de "simular" las acciones.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Así es. La plataforma ya está escrita en PHP pero esta nueva funcionalidad puede estar escrita en otro lenguaje. Lo que yo necesito hacer es obtener una serie de credenciales de una base de datos con un LP, ejecutar una aplicación de Android en un emulador de escritorio, y con la ayuda de un programa de automatización loguearme una app y completar unas acciones. ¿Puedes aceptarme en Skype?

Comment: @AgustinM. Echa un vistazo al comentario que le he puesto a Luiggi. Todo existe ya, tanto la plataforma, como el programa en el que tengo que realizar yo las acciones de forma automática

Comment: @AlbertoFernández Tu servidor es linux o windows?

Comment: Checa cURL de Php: http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

Hay una buena cantidad de herramientas diseñadas para le automatización de las pruebas de aplicaciones con interfaz gráfica de usuario.

Cada una posee sus propias características y alcances. Las más conocidas son:

- [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)
- [AscentialTest](http://www.zeenyx.com/AscentialTest.html)
- [TestPlant](http://www.testplant.com/)
- [Linux Desktop (GUI Application) Testing Project (GNU LDTP)](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/), que a pesar de su nombre sirve para automatizar pruebas en diferentes plataformas.
- [Maveryx](http://www.maveryx.com/)

La Wikipedia en inglés mantiene [una lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) (más o menos actualizada) de otras herramientas que podrían servirte. EMHO no hay una ideal para todos los casos así que te tocará evaluar la que más te conviene.

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede hacerse de muchas formas. Una de ellas podría ser:

En  el servidor unos varios scripts en bash que usen [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xdotool.1.html) para reproducir los movimientos/pulsaciones del ratón y las teclas. Por ejemplo el script de más abajo mueve  el ratón a la posición 0,0 y realiza una pulsación izquierda:

**moverraton.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool mousemove 0 0 click 1
```

Los scripts son invocados remotamente con ssh

```
ssh tuusuario@tuservidor /home/usuario/scripts/moverraton.sh
```

Y si quieres invocar scripts en función de los datos que obtienes de una BD desde php o cualquier otro lenguaje... deberías realizar las llamadas a los scripts remotos usando una librería ssh o ejecutando ssh con exec o la llamada similar del lenguaje de programación que uses.

```
<?
exec("ssh tuusuario@tuservidor /home/usuario/scripts/moverraton.sh");
?>
```

Conste que esto es sólo una sugerencia, se puede hacer de otras formas y el mismo sistema puede implementarse de maneras muy distintas. En vez de ssh para ejecutar los scripts remotos puedes implementar directamente un servidor web REST que se ocupe de la interacción con xdotool en función de las llamadas realizadas... y bueno... un sinfín de cosas ;-)